# mysql update one table with data from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting an issue with this update statement:

```
update customers
set customers.email = initialsynctemptable.thinkEmail,
    customers.packages = initialsynctemptable.thinkPackages 
FROM customers INNER JOIN initialsynctemptable
ON  customers.id = initialsynctemptable.customerID
```

and are using mySQL.  There is a squigly line under the FROM word.  Essentially I am trying to do an update one table (customers) with data from another table (initialsynctemptable).....Help!  Thanking you

Comment: `from` is not used for this. RTLM: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE customers c INNER JOIN 
       initialsynctemptable i ON  c.id = i.customerID
   SET c.email = i.thinkEmail,
       c.packages = i.thinkPackages
```

Comment: another quick question if I can.  If thinkemail and thinkpackages are varchars which could have null values do you think i need a WHERE clause?  Thanking you

Comment: @Mat41 You're welcome. Glad it helped. Now if you want to prevent it from happening (assigning NULL values) then go ahead and filter those records out with `WHERE` clause.